# User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)

Tags: mysql

Hello I am using MySQL Workbench and I accidentally set the max_questions to 1 on root user. Now I am logged out, and I cannot log in. I waited 1 hour but I still get the error User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1) when testing the connection.

What should I do?

Comment: Where is your MySQL server located? Is it a localhost?

Comment: Yes. It is an EC-2 Amazon server running MySQL 5.1.73...

Comment: I SSH to the server and logged in to msyql... Tried to run:
UPDATE mysql.user SET max_questions = 0 WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
and got:
ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)

Comment: you might be able to do this from myphpadmin SQL section SET @MAX_QUESTIONS=0; // This will set unlimited.
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: I normally log from Workbench and directly on the command line, but after trying to run any command it shows:

ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)

Is there a way to reset the root settings. I am afraid that is the only admin user I have....

Comment: Now you have learned not too manually mess with the mysql.* tables i hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i feel for you!

the setting is per hour (i think), you dont have to wait the hour you can restart the MYSQL server
you could enable --skip-grant-tables
so via ssh

```
service mysql restart --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

next login and perform (via SSH command line)

```
mysql -h host -u root -ppassword UPDATE mysql.user SET max_questions = 0 WHERE user='root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then restart mysql using

```
service mysql restart
```

good luck

Comment: Would that work if I edited max_questions instead of max_connections to 1? I am afraid that question expires by logging in.... I will try!

Comment: For some reason I get: mysql: unrecognized service

Comment: might be mysqld

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: I get the same error ERROR 1226 (42000): User 'root' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 1)

Comment: I was able to change the settings. Thanks for your help and quick responses @Clint